# How can I hide sidenav items dynamically based on login status in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material, frontend

I am developing a small web-api for online invoice exchange.
I decided to use Asp.net core for my backend and Angular8 for frontend.
Since I need role based views that don't alter that much, I want to make certain items in my angular material sidenav visible only to certain users.

Right now I am using `*ngIf` statements that refer to a variable containing the active user role. When I login a logout button and list items based on the user role should appear, but the change only happens after I reload the entire page. How can I change it so that the sidenav updates instantly on certain events, like login without having to reload the entire Page?

I tried to use `*ngIf` statements corresponding to a variable stored in the corresponding component and in my **user.service.ts** file in the shared folder.

I also tried using an EventEmitter in the **login.component.ts** to invoke the necessary changes in mySidenav.
The login event happens within my login component which is referred to in my **app.component.html** via `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Thank you in advance!

picture of sidenav and login screen:
[image: picture of sidenav and login screen]

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav class="sidenav" mode="push">
      <mat-nav-list>
          <a mat-list-item [routerLink]='["/home"]' [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]' ><mat-icon>home</mat-icon>&nbsp;Home</a>
          <a mat-list-item [routerLink]='["/form"]' [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]' ><mat-icon>assignment</mat-icon>&nbsp;Formular</a>
          <a mat-list-item [routerLink]='["/user/registration"]' [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]' ><mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>&nbsp;Nutzer Verwalten</a>
          <a mat-list-item [routerLink]='["/profile"]' [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]' ><mat-icon>account_box</mat-icon>&nbsp;Profil</a>
          <a mat-list-item [routerLink]='["/test"]' [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]' ><mat-icon>build</mat-icon>&nbsp;Test Page</a>
          <a *ngIf="login" mat-list-item (click)="onLogout()"><mat-icon>vpn_key</mat-icon>&nbsp;Logout</a>
      </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content class="sidenav-content">
      <mat-toolbar class="toolbar mat-elevation-z12" style="background-color: lightyellow">
          <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
          </button>
          SmartWeb
        </mat-toolbar>
  <main class="content">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>
</mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

The sixth `mat-list-item` is corresponding to a variable `login: boolean;` in the **app.component.ts**. Login is set true when a user successfully submits the login form, but the sidenav remains unchanged until I reload the page.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a [mcve], please strip the code to showcase the exact issue, you will improve your chances to get an answer. Also just a small remark, why are you using `style` tags in the html, I'm sure you have a sass, css or scss file where you can add styles :) But this has nothing to do with your issue, just a comment. Also I see no use of `ngIf`, which you are talking about in your question.

Comment: have you tried using observable ?

Comment: @AJT_82 Thanks for your feedback. I edited my question accordingly. The style section will go into a css file later on.

Comment: @user8351493 I did, though I'm pretty sure i didn't do it properly

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz with a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Any chance we can see at least your logout function? You wouldn't believe what odd things I have seen that people can get wrong by accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Subject or BehaviourSubject if you need for this.

Basically onInit of your sideNav component, subscribe to Subject, and when user logs in or whenever an event occurs where you need to inform your side menu, fire the Subject,

basically,

In a service that you can inject in both sidemenu and where you need to fire event from, do

```
userLogin: Subject<any> //or whatever data type you are sending

constructor(){
   this.userLogin = new Subject()
}
```

Then inject the service in your sidemenu and other component

When user logs in or something

From the source, do

`x-service.userLogin.next(ANY_DATA) //or no data`

In the sidemenu

````
x-service.userLogin.subscribe((ANY_DATA) => {
   //whatever action you want to take
})```
````